# URL with strange UTF8 symbol

Tags: nginx, utf-8

On nginx, I have a file / URL that contain German word "**frühling**".

When URL is accessed from Mac + Safari there is a problem.

I copied / pasted the two URL's - correct one and the one from Mac and here are the result:

```
[nmmm@zenbook ~]$ cat > a
frühling
^C
[nmmm@zenbook ~]$ cat > b
frühling
^C
[nmmm@zenbook ~]$ xxd a
0000000: 66 72 75 cc 88 68 6c 69 6e 67 0a              fru..hling.
[nmmm@zenbook ~]$ xxd b
0000000: 66 72 c3 bc    68 6c 69 6e 67 0a              fr..hling.
```

"a" is correct, "b" is incorrect. Seems the difference is just after the umlaut "**ü**", there is additional normal "**u**". Also umlaut "**ü**" is different somehow.

Where this symbol come from?
My client sometimes uses MsWord or LibreOffice to prepare the things.
Is there a way nginx to handle (reconstruct) it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching Google I found following:
https://coderwall.com/p/gc079w/debugging-encodings-and-character-sets

seems there are two ways to do u umlaut:

> Correct utf8 encoding is (you would see **c3 bc** in the hexdump):
>
> ```
> U+00FC  ü  c3 bc   LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIA.
> ```
>
> A valid UTF-8 character sequence that displays identically, but is not
>   a "ü" (again, 75 cc 88 in the hexdump):
>
> ```
> U+0075  u   75      LATIN SMALL LETTER U
> U+0308  ̈    cc 88   COMBINING DIAERESIS
> ```

**UPDATE:**

using find you can find all files with correct or wrong umlauts, works in "normal" way:

> ```
> find . -name '*ü*'
> ```

however you need to copy/paste correct umlaut "way" or make a bash file.

Possible solution I am after is creating symlinks, that can be done with the output of the find.

(still looking how this can be fixed from nginx level)

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you find any solution for this?
How can we create `bash` file. Please help me in this

Comment: yes. we redirected all those 404 errors to a php file that reads the "request" and make a symlink:

https://gist.github.com/nmmmnu/8da6e9654401132df071d7e69aa197c4

pay attention to `$correct` array it is look the same, but it follows the UTF encoding as described. As I can not produce it by hand, I used copy / paste to produce it.

have similar solution for French as well